# Find the pdf of a piecewise defined random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given are the probability density functions of the three random variables $P,Q,R$. The random variables are pairwise independent.  We construct a new random variable

$$S = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}  Q & \text{ if }  P<0 \\ R & \text{ if }  P\geq 0 \end{array} \right. .$$

How can we calculate the pdf of $S$?

Comment: $P$ isn't used, check for typos.

Comment: 1. Independence? 2. Personal tries?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks, that was indeed a typo, I updated it.

Comment: @Did Yes they are pairwise independent. I have no idea how to go about this, but I need it in an application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_<$ and $p_\ge$ be the probabilities for $P<0$ and $P\ge0$.

The pdf of $S$ is $p_<\cdot Q+p_\ge\cdot R$.

Comment: How do we calculate p_< and p_{ge} ?

Comment: @SaiNikhil: calculate ?